# Simplifying x'y'+y'z+xz+xy+yz'

Tags: boolean-algebra

Someone help me to simplify this boolean expression.

$x'y'+y'z+xz+xy+yz'$

I understand the laws used but still not getting the exact answer. I would appreciate if someone solved this for me.

My attempt so far:

$$x'y'+y'z+xz+xy+yz'= x'y'+y'z+(y+y')xz+xy+yz'$$ $$= x'y'+y'z+yxz+y'xz+xy+yz'$$ $$= x'y'+y'z(x+1)+xy(z+1)+yz'$$ $$= x'y'+y'z+xy+yz'$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: For this type of question it would be more useful if you share what you have tried so far. You surely have tried something as you arrived at a different result than the supposed correct result. When doing boolean algebra truth tables are good to check correctness.

Comment: @skyking has suggested a good approach. There are only 8 possibilities to look at.

Comment: Both $xz+yz'+x'y'$ and $xy+x'z'+y'z$ are correct, though they look different. If you've got one of them, it is correct.

Comment: the result I have tried so far is  x'y'+y'z+xz+xy+yz'=  x'y'+y'z+(y+y')xz+xy+yz'= x'y'+y'z+yxz+y'xz+xy+yz'= x'y'+y'z(x+1)+xy(z+1)+yz'= x'y'+y'z+xy+yz'    No idea how to continue. As I checked on the truth table, the result is 1.

Comment: Please move your try from a comment to the question itself.  Use \$ to delimit mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing your attempt. You reached $$x'y'+y'z+xy+yz'$$

Now $xy=xy(z+z')=xyz+xyz'$, but $xyz'+yz'=yz'$, so we get $$x'y'+y'z+xyz+yz'$$

Similarly, $y'z=x'y'z+xy'z$, but $x'y'+x'y'z=x'y'$, so we get $$x'y'+xy'z+xyz+yz'=x'y'+x(y+y')z+yz'=x'y'+xz+yz'$$

Another way of expressing it is $$(xy'z'+x'yx)'$$ so you are not going to get any simpler (6 of the 8 expressions in the truth table are true and 2 are false).

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for the

**Consensus Theorem**

$xy +y'z = xy +y'z +xz$

Ok, applying that to your original statement, we see that between $x'y'$ and $xz$ we can get rid of $y'z$, and between $xz$ and $yz'$ we can get rid of $xy$, leaving us with:

$x'y'+ xz + yz'$